# Adding custom images to nodes

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Using Sigma.js I want to add custom images to the graph's nodes. I found [a plugin](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/pull/106), included nodeShapes.js and plotter.js, then added an image attribute :

```
var imgUri="somepicture.png"

sigInst.addNode(id,{
                    'x': Math.random(),
                    'y': Math.random(),
                    'label': data.nodes[i].val,
                //  'color': color,                         commenting this line out to add custom images to the nodes              
                    'image':{'url':imgUri},
                    'cluster': clusters['cluster_id']
});
```

But the graph remains unchanged and I still see the default dots.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the new version of Sigma that came out a few days ago. There you can add custom images on the nodes, but make sure to specify that you use Canvas renderer, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have used the new release but that would break my current code. I can use the new version but the syntax has been changed a lot. Also the creator of the plugin mentioned changes in files Plotter.js and nodeShapes.js(as per github).The new version comes along with this plugin as the part of core code. Can you suggest changes in reference to previous version of sigma??