# Use custom images on nodes in Sigma js

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002611/adding-custom-images-to-nodes-in-sigma-js#answer-21802298), I should use ***canvas renderer*** so that images can be displayed in nodes. First of all I create a *graphClass*:

```
graphClass.g = {
    nodes: [],
    edges: []
}
```

Then, I create each node:

```
graphClass.g.nodes.push({
      id: 'n' + data.id,
      label: data.username,
      x: Math.random(),
      y: Math.random(),
      size: 20,
      type: 'image',
      url: data.picture
});
```

where `data.picture` is an image URL.

(edges are not relevant here)

And finally, I instantiate Sigma:

```
s = new sigma({
    graph: g,
    renderer: {
        container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
        type: 'canvas'
    },
    settings: {
        defaultLabelColor: '#fff',
        labelColor: '#fff',
        enableEdgeHovering: false
    }
});
```

This works as expected, except the images. I can't see them, and black nodes are displayed instead. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. I had to use the example at [github](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/custom-node-renderer.html)

I've just copied this code:

```
sigma.utils.pkg('sigma.canvas.nodes');
sigma.canvas.nodes.image = (function() {
    var _cache = {},
        _loading = {},
        _callbacks = {};
    // Return the renderer itself:
    var renderer = function(node, context, settings) {
        var args = arguments,
            prefix = settings('prefix') || '',
            size = node[prefix + 'size'],
            color = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor'),
            url = node.url;
        if (_cache[url]) {
            context.save();
            // Draw the clipping disc:
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(
                node[prefix + 'x'],
                node[prefix + 'y'],
                node[prefix + 'size'],
                0,
                Math.PI * 2,
                true
            );
            context.closePath();
            context.clip();
            // Draw the image
            context.drawImage(
                _cache[url],
                node[prefix + 'x'] - size,
                node[prefix + 'y'] - size,
                2 * size,
                2 * size
            );
            // Quit the "clipping mode":
            context.restore();
            // Draw the border:
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(
                node[prefix + 'x'],
                node[prefix + 'y'],
                node[prefix + 'size'],
                0,
                Math.PI * 2,
                true
            );
            context.lineWidth = size / 5;
            context.strokeStyle = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor');
            context.stroke();
        } else {
            sigma.canvas.nodes.image.cache(url);
            sigma.canvas.nodes.def.apply(
                sigma.canvas.nodes,
                args
            );
        }
    };
    // Let's add a public method to cache images, to make it possible to
    // preload images before the initial rendering:
    renderer.cache = function(url, callback) {
        if (callback)
            _callbacks[url] = callback;
        if (_loading[url])
            return;
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            _loading[url] = false;
            _cache[url] = img;
            if (_callbacks[url]) {
                _callbacks[url].call(this, img);
                delete _callbacks[url];
            }
        };
        _loading[url] = true;
        img.src = url;
    };
    return renderer;
})();
```

and instantiate sigma like this (caching images):

```
images.forEach(function(url) {
    sigma.canvas.nodes.image.cache(
        url,
        function() {
            if (++loaded === images.length) {
                s = new sigma({
                    graph: g,
                    renderer: {
                    // IMPORTANT:
                    // This works only with the canvas renderer, so the
                    // renderer type set as "canvas" is necessary here.
                        container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
                        type: 'canvas'
                    },
                    settings: {
                        maxNodeSize: 20,
                        defaultLabelColor: '#fff',
                        labelColor: '#fff',
                        enableEdgeHovering: false
                    }
                });                                
            }
        }
    );
});
```

And images are now displayed on nodes.