# Sigma JS - Customs Icon Image on nodes

Tags: sigma.js

i try refer to the example on [Use custom images on nodes in Sigma js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810127/use-custom-images-on-nodes-in-sigma-js)

but i keep having error on 'Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined', wonder anyone can advice me on how to fix it and able to display the icon on the nodes

Comment: Which version of sigma are you using ?

Comment: @logisma , i currently using version 1.5.2

Comment: you should know that this version is no longer maintained. You should consider to upgrade to the version 2

Comment: yes i know but can with you for version 2 does it still solve my error?